# Dynamic allocation of a primitive type variable in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, primitive-types, dynamic-allocation

Can I dynamically allocate a primitive type variable, say `int`? I can't see how this could be done other than to wrap it into an object `Integer` or into a single-element array `int[1]`.

I tried:

```
int i = new int(5);
```

Is it forbidden? If so, why?

### EDIT

Possible (theoretical) application - creating a collection-like data structure for storing primitive types.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean _dynamically allocate_? How is it different than `int i = 5`?

Comment: putting in onto a heap. `int i = 5` puts it on a stack.

Comment: It does not put it on a stack. The place where it resides is decided by the location of the variable i. If it is not inside a function, you are correct else it would be on the heap memory.In Java you can not create instances of primitive data types like you can do for Reference types. Primitive types are built in, whereas reference types are classes whose objects may be created. primitive types can only take `literals` as their values. This makes sense since primitive types are designed to directly hold the values in memory rather than a reference to a memory address.

Comment: @BatScream Are you sure `int i = 5` can be placed in the heap memory? I can't see how would that be possible apart from the case when it is a field of an object. Inside a method, it would be placed on stack as I understand it, contrary to what you say.

Comment: regardless, the issue is, java is a "pass by value" language.  you cannot pass the address of a primitive because java has no concept of passing addresses.  so "dynamically allocating a primitive" makes no sense in java.  you CAN dynamically allocate a Collection of primitives or an array of primitives, but since arrays are objects, you're just creating them as attributes of an object.

Comment: @him actually, it can be a Collection of wrappers of primitive types (Collection of Integer not int). you cannot create a Collection of primitives in Java. Apart from that, I think you're right. So the answer would be that it is impossible.